# What is a good data structure for finding which region contains a point?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, point, region, quadtree

I'm looking for a data structure that supports finding which of "n" regions contains a point "p". I was looking at Quadtree's and R-trees however I don't think they fit exactly what I'm looking for.

In essence I want to be able to add some number of 3 dimensional rectangular regions to this tree, and then be able to test a 3 dimensional point against this tree and return which region most tightly constrains the point. No regions will have overlapping borders.

The naive algorithm I'm currently using is to simply test the point "p" against each dimension of each rectangular region.

```
for(region in regionList):
    if(p.x > region.x1 && p.x < region.x2 && p.y > region.y1 && py < region.y2 && p.z > region.z1 && p.z < region.z2)
        return region
end
```

This runs in O(n) time where n is the number of regions. I'd like the search to take O(log n) as a point Quadtree does for finding 2d points.

Comment: This looks promising. 

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/multidimensional-book-flyer.pdf

Comment: Since the regions cannot overlap, at most, only one can contain the point. This makes the question of "...return which region most tightly constrains the point." a logical impossibility. 1, and only 1 can constrain the point.

Comment: This app might make very good use of the new SIMD Extensions, with 16 128 bit registers for 3D graphics apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a QuadTree which stores regions like a MX-CIF tree. It's essentially a QuadTree based on 2 dimensions (x,y). Once you find an appropriate Node which contains the point in terms of (x,y), you can check to see if it contains the point in all three (x,y,z) dimensions.

I've done [something similar in Java](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/QuadTree.java).

You can also look into Octree which is a 3-dimensional QuadTree.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly. Are you suggesting that I check to see if the point is in the xy region using the Quadtree and then just independently check to see if the point is also within that region's z boundaries? What happens if I have two regions, one above the other? What would the Quadtree return?

Comment: A point cannot exist in multiple regions, right? Wasn't that part of your problem statement?

Comment: Right, but since the MX-CIF tree tests if a point is within a 2d region. If I have 3d regions then a point could be within the projections of two 3d regions without being in both of those regions. Unless you meant that I adapt the MX-CIF tree to 3 dimensions, in which case that should work.

Comment: A point can only be in the same XY space of two non-overlapping boundary rectangles if they occupy different Z space. "Above the other" implies a different Y space, not Z space. I think you mean "behind the other" - in which case they would have the same XY space, but a different Z space, so Justin's suggest works fine.

Comment: In any case, only one rectangle, if any, can contain the point, so the question of "which constrains the point most tightly" cannot be answered by your suggested construct. Perhaps you need to give your problem definition some closer scrutiny.

Comment: @RocketRoy The only down side to a structure like this is it'll eventually break down if all your regions have the same (x,y) values but different (z) values. So, it'll essentially be a List which is O(n) but if you know that'll likely not happen, it should suffice.

Comment: @Justin, Agreed. If you read my deleted comments, you'll remember I used trees with a Right, Left, and Next_Dim pointer. When I'd searched a tree for the X dimension, I proceeded to the root of the Y, and likewise, after resolving Y, to the root of Z. A seriously challenging piece of code to write if you want it to be self-balancing, but it will resolve any number of dimensions - 28 in my case. Also possible to have separate trees share upper nodes that are the same, so they occupy the same memory as well as nodes, provided you have a limter for depth/dimensions.

Comment: @Justin, doesn't this seem more like a grid population problem? "Not overlapping" seems to require uniformly shaped rectangles, or else large gaps will appear in the contained space.

Comment: A problem I would find more compelling would be "When and where did two objects pass closest to each other?". As a cyclist riding with a Garmin GPS, and amateur pilot, this would be a cool app, consuming Garmin traces as input. This would also add an obviously dominant primary 4th dimension - TIME. Thus my infinite dimensional solution would provide a solution where no others I've seen would.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Segment Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and [KD Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136960/querying-a-collection-of-rectangles-for-the-overlap-of-an-input-rectangle).